# Comparing several webcam snapshots and saving Them when there is motion Using matlab

Tags: matlab

My question is how would i get live snapshots from my webcam and only save an image when there is motion, I would like to save several images i.e whenever there is motion the images do not overwrite so that at the end i will be able to see various captured motions

Comment: do you already have a way of getting the live image stream into matlab?

Comment: Yeah and i have only been able to to compare two images and save one only images the mistake i made is that i did not put the code here and i cant edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i was able to come up with a simple solution for my problem as below; it saves images only when there is motion and also adds a time stamp

```
clear;
clc;
vid  = videoinput('winvideo', '1');
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
start(vid)
%preview(vid)
while true;
img = getsnapshot(vid);
pause(2)
img1 = getsnapshot(vid);

img12 = rgb2gray(img1);
img13 = rgb2gray(img);
diff1 =sum(sum(img12 - img13));
  if diff1>100000;
      display ('motion')
      counter  = 1;
      baseDir  = 'H:\';
      fname = [baseDir ,'Wysla_', num2str((strrep(datestr(clock),':','-'))),'.jpg']; 
      % make a file name
      while exist(fname,'file')
          counter = counter + 1;
        fname = [baseDir ,'Wysla_', num2str(counter),'.jpg'];
      end  
      imwrite(img1, fname);

  else 
      display('No motion')
  end;
end
```

This is all  and it was very simple only thing i can mention is the strrep(datestr(clock),':','-')  this a way of saving the image time stamped and since there are semi colons in the date string the strrep() replaecs them with the hyphen or anything else

av fun.